# JBoss - jms-bridge - javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: invalid name or password

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, tibco, bridge

I am trying to create a jms-bridge from JBoss EAP 6.4 to TIbco EMS 8 (I think).

I setup the below in the standalone config:

```html
<jms-bridge name="TibcoBridge" module="org.tbco">
         <source>
             <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory"/>
             <destination name="mdm.output.queue"/>
         </source>
         <target>
             <connection-factory name="XAQueueConnectionFactory"/>
             <destination name="sync.queue.test"/>
             <context>
                 <property key="java.naming.factory.initial"                   value="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"/>
                 <property key="java.naming.provider.url" value="tibjmsnaming://jms:7222"/>
                 <property key="java.naming.security.principal" value="consumer"/>
                 <property key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="password"/>
             </context>
         </target>
         <quality-of-service>AT_MOST_ONCE</quality-of-service>
         <failure-retry-interval>100000</failure-retry-interval>
         <max-retries>10</max-retries>
         <max-batch-size>10</max-batch-size>
         <max-batch-time>100</max-batch-time>
</jms-bridge>
```

I setup the below directory structure for the module:

```html
[jboss@poc-informatica-jboss01 /usr/share/jbossas/modules/system/layers/base/org/tbco]$ ls -ltr main
total 592
-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss 271790 Sep 19 13:00 tibcrypt.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss 323650 Sep 19 13:00 tibjms.jar
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jboss jboss      6 Sep 19 13:03 attachments
-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss    734 Sep 19 13:31 module.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss      0 Sep 19 14:09 derby.log
 
[jboss@poc-informatica-jboss01 /usr/share/jbossas/modules/system/layers/base/org/tbco/main]$ cat module.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.tbco">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>
 
 
<resources>
    <!-- Insert resources required to connect to the source or target   -->
    <resource-root path="."/>
    <resource-root path="tibcrypt.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="tibjms.jar"/>
</resources>
 
 
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="org.hornetq"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.common-core"/>
    <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
[jboss@poc-informatica-jboss01 /usr/share/jbossas/modules/system/layers/base/org/tbco/main]$
```

Upon startup, I am seeing the below error message:

```
14:15:37,039 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Thread-98) HQ122010: Failed to connect JMS Bridge TibcoBridge: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: invalid name or password
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:575)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._create(TibjmsConnection.java:1330)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection.<init>(TibjmsConnection.java:4115)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnection.<init>(TibjmsQueueConnection.java:36)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createImpl(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:173)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createConnection(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:253)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsXAConnectionFactory.createConnection(TibjmsXAConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.createConnection(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1155)
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.setupJMSObjects(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1370)
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.setupJMSObjectsWithRetry(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1504)
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.access$2400(JMSBridgeImpl.java:80)
    at org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl$FailureHandler.run(JMSBridgeImpl.java:2132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
```

Reached here after half a day of struggle tweaking numerous mistakes.
I have confirmed that the user and password works. Even tried with admin user and password but same error.
Does tibco expect password to be encrypted or something?

Please assist with jumping across hopefully the final hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for answer:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/976162#976162

The credentials you need to specify are for JMS, not for JNDI.
Have you tried to set it in the target'user and password?

```
     <target>
         <connection-factory name="XAQueueConnectionFactory"/>
         <destination name="sync.queue.test"/>
         <user>consumer</user>
         <password>password</password>
         <context>
             <property key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"/>
             <property key="java.naming.provider.url" value="tibjmsnaming://jms:7222"/>
             <property key="java.naming.security.principal" value="consumer"/>
             <property key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="password"/>
         </context>
     </target>
```